# audio/video in phoneGap?

Tags: mobile-website, cordova

Can you please give me any sample related to audio/video? if the browser doesn't support HTML5, is it throw any error or ??

thanks

sri

Answer (score 1):

on Iphone/Android:

```
m = new Media("mysong.mp3");
m.play()
```

on BlackBerry/Palm/Symbian

```
a = new Audio("mysong.mp3");
a.play();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So phoneGap isn't based on Browser right?